# 2 horizontal scrollbar are overlapped in IE. (In Google Chrome/Mozilla works fine)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I implemented a modal window (pop-up) and when I try to resize it, everything works fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla, because both browsers display 2 horizontal scrollbars. In Internet Explorer, scrollbars are overlapped and you cannot access content of the page. Please, have a look on ScreenShots and help me with a solution for this problem.

[image: Google Chrome]

[image: Internet Explorer]